# Create an .app file for os x with eclipse in java

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, .app

I've got a problem. I have written a java application in eclipse on my mac with os x 10.9. To export the application as a .jar is no problem. It works perfectly. If I export it as a mac os x application bundle in eclipse everything is right, too but when I start the created .app file nothing happens.When I started the .app file using the Ternimal there was a error 
`Nils:desktop Nils$ open Test_003.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/Nils/Desktop/Test_003.app.`

Maybe I have to add something in the export assistant in eclipse (like the working directory            or some classpaths). Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Nils

Comment: If Eclipse shows error, put it here, please

Comment: eclipse doesn't but the terminal. I've edited it in my question